Is this a correct way of defining the scheme morphism $\operatorname{Spec}k_y\rightarrow Y$?
Let $Y$ be a scheme and $y\in Y$ a point. Let $k_y$ be the residue field of the stalk $(\mathcal{O}_{Y})_y$. I am trying to define the scheme morphism $\operatorname{Spec}k_y\rightarrow Y$, but was confused by this post.
In particular, I don't see what the issue is. I would like to define the topological map by $g:\langle 0\rangle\in \operatorname{Spec}k_y\rightarrow y\in Y$. For the sheaf we  first note that if $y\notin U$ then $\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}k_y}(g^{-1}(U))=\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}k_y}(\emptyset)=\{0\}$, and  that if $y\in U$ then
$\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}k_y}(g^{-1}(U))=k_y$. So we define $g^\sharp:\mathcal{O}_Y\rightarrow g_*\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}k_y}$ on open sets by:
\begin{align}
g^\sharp_U(s)=\begin{cases}
[s_y]\in k_y&\text{ if }y\in U\\
0\in \{0\}&\text{ if }y\notin U
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $[s_y]$ is my notation for mapping $s$ to the element $s_y$ in the stalk, and then projecting to the residue field.
I feel like this works because taking stalks commutes with restrictions, and the projection map is fixed. Is this the right idea?

Yes, this is fine. What confused you about the linked post?

That you have to somehow show this well defined?
